# Create a Script by bringing the URL from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

`<a href="/javascript.js">Open JavaScript</a>`:- this code isn't editable as it is locked by the Host! So also I can't add any selector inside it!

But I can add another code outside of it. Like:- `<ex ex="ex"><a href="/javascript.js">Open JavaScript</a></ex>`

So, I want to create a `<script src="/javascript.js"></script>` by fetching the URL from `<a href="/javascript.js">Open JavaScript</a>`.

They also didn't allow PHP there, otherwise I could do it myself. There is only one way to do it via JavaScript.

And I don't want to add the script inside `<head>` tags! It should be in the footer (`<div class="body-footer"> Here </div>`). There are not only one JavaScript link in the page, there are so many JavaScript links. So also I can't use `$("a[href$='.js']");`. Its became more tougher for me.

So how can I do this using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: So, you want to add `<script src='/javascript.js'></script>` in parent of `<a>` tag. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation, where `<script>` tag is added before `<a>` with value of `href`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
     var hrefValue = $("div#test a").attr("href");
        $("div#test a").before("<script src='"+hrefValue+"'><\/script>");
        console.log($("#test").html());
    });
});
</script>

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="test">
   <a href="/javascript.js">Open JavaScript</a>
 </div>

</br></br>
<button>CLICK it, to add href value of anchor tag to newly created sibling element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I got my answer by modifying some mistakes & by customising some codes! Thanks! 

Comment: Great @user8383072. If this answer helps you, then please Accept/upvote the answer that will close the question

Comment: Look! Please remove `</style>`. & change `<\br>` into `<br />`